# How to view a reactive form result in an Angular Material Tabs?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I am working on a testing system so there will be questions with a list of answers in a test. I am going to use mat-tab to integrate reactive forms with mat-tab. So below via forms question and answers will be created in the **content** tab.

[image]

After saving the result, it is like in below:

[image]

But through a new window.

How can I add this result in the **display** tab? Is it possible to view reactive form results in one window via the mat-tab menu in Angular Material?

Comment: can u replicate this in stackblitz?

Comment: @Vignesh, actually it was taken from this site. https://anketolog.ru/survey/manage/editor/646789

Comment: a ReactiveForm exist in the .ts for the whole component. So the only you need is use, e.g. `<div *ngFor="let option of form.get('options').value">{{option}}</div>`